# Selecting one value from an array called by a query in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

Basically I have a query called using PHP:

```
<?php $result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Colours WHERE Type = 'type1' ");


while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) { 

if ($row['ColourID'] == "1") {

    $sayclass1="imgactive";

    }else{

    $sayclass1="imginactive"; }


            ?>
```

As you can see once I execute the query I then loop it, the problem is that it returns an array, now in some instances I need to use the full array, but I would like to be able to select one entry from it for if statements and such. For example:

```
<img id="h" src="<?php echo $row['thumbimg']; ?>
```

now thumbimg is a column in my DB, and it just holds a url. However due to the fact its an array the picture doesn't display because its echoing all the values, so instead of **images/image1.png** for example it is echoing **images/image1.png images/image2.png images/image3.png** etc etc...

I hope that makes sense, and can anyone tell me how to manipulate the query/code slight to still return all the entries but to select certain values from the arrays please?

Comment: You need to select one of the fetched rows and use that as you say with $row['thumbimg']; please check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: BTW, you have a typo `if ($row['ColourID'] = "1")`. `=` should be `==`.

Comment: Unable to decode Your question :(

Comment: Thanks you for the typo comment, and im using MS SQL not My SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the img tag with in for each if you want to show all the images

```
foreach($row[thumbimg] as $img):
<img id="h" src="<?php echo $img; ?>
end foreach;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Colours WHERE Type = 'type1' ");


while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) { 

     if ($row['ColourID'] == "1") {

        $sayclass1="imgactive";

    }else{

        $sayclass1="imginactive"; 
    }
 echo '<img id="h" src="'.$row['thumbimg'].'">';
}

?>
```

Using this above code, you will get one image per line from the database. The part of code you have copy-pasted is not enough to determine where your mistake is and why `$row['thumbimg']` contains a concatenated value of the result.